# Finding active eth port while installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: networking, system-installation

At work I was just tasked to rebuild a testbed of 80+ systems and each system has 20 10G interfaces, the  They all need Ubuntu 12.04.02 Server x64 to be installed on them.

I do not have physical access to the, only LO / CIMC access to them so its almost the same as having direct console access.

This would be a simple scripting, but I ran into a catch. The group of interns that installed all them did not keep the same eth port.  When installing it looks like they rolled a D20 and installed the Switch 10G connection on what number came up. Maybe there is a pattern, but I can not see one.  The first 6 systems have connections as follows.:  eth0, eth2, eth3, eth0, eth10, eth14.  If you see a pattern, let me know!

When installing I need to detect the only active Ethernet interface. In Fedora I would normally use ethtool or ethtool-lite and script an installer.  The Ubuntu Server installer does not seem to have this.

And before you ask, I do not have switch access for these systems so matching MAC addresses to Switch logs will not work.

Comment: Does `ip link show | grep -v "NO-CARRIER"` help?

Comment: Good idea, it looks like they do not come up until you configure the interfaces.  All of them show no link, even systems I know have a link on a few interfaces.  Now if I run this on a configured and installed system, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the install media you could install ethtool by running:

```
apt-get install ethtool
```

If they are installed based on the same disk image. I would recommend to remove /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules It will be regenerated on the next reboot based on the devices actual in the machine. That should fixed the issue with the random interface naming.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this worked. Thanks for the answer.